# Rails Devise: authenticate either two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm building Rails app with three models for devise : Administrator, Teacher, Student.
I would like to create a page that administrators and teachers can access.

I know how to create a page that users of one role can access. like

`before_action :authenticate_model!`

But how do I do when I would like to check the authentication of either administrator or teacher.

Auto redirect path can be fixed one. For example, if a user visited the page without logging in, the user will be redirected to teacher's login page with a hyperlink to administrator.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the [devise_group](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/Helpers/ClassMethods:devise_group) option.

**Example:**

```
inside BlogsController (or any other controller, it doesn't matter which):
  devise_group :blogger, contains: [:user, :admin]

Generated methods:
  authenticate_blogger!  # Redirects unless user or admin are signed in
  blogger_signed_in?     # Checks whether there is either a user or an admin signed in
  current_blogger        # Currently signed in user or admin
  current_bloggers       # Currently signed in user and admin

Use:
  before_action :authenticate_blogger!              # Redirects unless either a user or an admin are authenticated
  before_action ->{ authenticate_blogger! :admin }  # Redirects to the admin login page
  current_blogger :user                             # Preferably returns a User if one is signed in
```